# How do I send an API key in a response to an Angular client app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm trying to route my api key from NodeJS to an Angular client app by using the $http, but I'm not sure how to do it. Here's my NodeJS file:

```
//http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

//GET http://localhost:3000
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var env = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;
  request({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    qs:req.query
  },function(err,response,body){
    if(err) return res.send(500,err);
    res.send(body);
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

and here's my Angular file:

```
NewsApp.directive('weather', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
   location: '=?'
  },
  controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http){
   $scope.location = 'Seattle,WA';
    console.log($scope.location);
     $http({
       url:'/api/weather',
       params:{
         q:$scope.location,
         APPID: //place API KEY here,
         units:'imperial'
        }
     }).success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        var weatherData = data.weather[0];
        $scope.temperature = Math.round(data.main.temp);
        $scope.city = data.name;
        $scope.image = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + weatherData.icon + '.png';
     })
   }],
    template:'<li class="weather"> \
            Today\'s temperature is: {{temperature}}&deg;<img src="{{image}}">\
            </li>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true
 }
});
```

When I do it manually in my angular file in params object after APPID, my app works fine, but I don't want my api key to be visible, so I would like to pass it in through the backend using my .env file using the the variable env in my nodejs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to modify the query string before forwarding it to the API server.  So instead of including APPID in the query string parameters on the client side, try adding it before forwarding the request.

```
...
//GET http://localhost:3000
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  req.query.APPID = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY; 
  request({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    qs:req.query
},
...
```

Comment: Thank you Chris!!!...This totally worked! I'm not sure what it's doing, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the key to the response on the server:

```
//GET http://localhost:3000
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var env = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;
  request({
    url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather',
    qs:req.query
  },function(err,response,body){
    if(err) return res.send(500,err);
    res.send({app_key: env, data: body});
  });
});
```

In your Angular client app, you make a 'GET' request for the key. Once received, you can make a consequent request to the weather API:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000'
}).success(function(data) {
  var app_key = data['app_key'];

  // make the request to the API
  http({
    url:'/api/weather',
    params: {
      q: $scope.location,
      APPID: app_key,
      units:'imperial'
    }
  })
})
```